# Archive of historic Firefox builds for Windows?

Tags: firefox, windows

For testing web content in Firefox I'm searching for old versions of Firefox  Windows installers. [Evolt](http://browsers.evolt.org/) is not up to date with historic Firefox builds. I'm looking for just the main point releases.  Sources can be downloaded from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org) (MDN formerly MDC) but I don't want to build the browsers - I just want to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [OldVersion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/Mozilla_Firefox.html) -- everything back to Firefox 0.8

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option: have you tried browsershots.org?

Comment: I have seen it and forgot all about it. This is a good suggestion. Thanks.